# Termiated after corporate takeover without severence

Tags: termination

I was let go yesterday after 27 years. My company had terminated us 7 months ago during the takeover and the new owner rehired us for the same jobs on the same day. Now I am fired with 2 weeks notice and no severance. What are my rights?

Comment: that highly depends on your location an contract. We can't answer this as is. Please edit and supply more details. "What are my rights" will probably end up getting this question closed.

Comment: without the nation, state or region, and locality, we cannot answer this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk to a lawyer ASAP. Your rights and what sort of compensation you are owed will vary depending on your location, industry, and all sorts of other factors. Only a lawyer with knowledge in such areas will be able to help you get what you're owed.

Comment: unless they were on probation when they got hired to the new company. Then they probably aren't owed anything because they were let go on probation to what is on paper a new job.

Comment: Even so, it would be better to talk to a lawyer who can tell you exactly what laws apply. Don't leave it up to research on the internet, or your own reading of the contracts.

Comment: @Cubemaster my point without all the details, we can't even say if it worth contacting a lawyer. They don't give advice for free. OP had that option from the start, but they chose to come here first. Blindly recommending a lawyer doesn't help in this case. Once we actually have details, then it may be appropriate to suggest a lawyer.

Comment: Good point, good point

Comment: Definitely talk to a lawyer. But probably your problem comes when you were terminated by the old company. You should have got serverance then, and you should have talked to a lawyer then. This sort of thing is exactly why the company wanted to pull the 'fire and rehire' trick.

Comment: If the OP is in the USA and in a right to work state, a consultation with a lawyer is a waste of time.

Comment: @RichardU exactly my point and not just a waste to time, a waste of money

Comment: @RichardU You mean if he's in an at-will state, which I believe 49 of them are.  In that case, OP will get whatever unemployment insurance is due and has no legal ground for more.  If this is outside the US, talking to a lawyer may be a very good idea.

Comment: @DavidThornley keyword MAY. without the information required to make a recommendation, we shouldn't.

Comment: @DavidThornley no, only 27 states are right to work states.  so location, even within the US, matters.

Comment: @RichardU, "right to work" is about the ability work without being forced to join a union.  "At will" is the issue in this case, which has its own set of complexity across states